# Time series composite of python-xarray.

Tags: python, time-series, python-xarray

I have a python `x-array` dataset with dimensions `x`,`y`,`t` and at least two variables at each coordinate. I was wondering if there exists any `x-array` method that can help "project" or "composite" values on an axis of my choice.

The figure I [drafted](https://www.draw.io/) up below is an example of what I mean by compositing on a time axis. In the figure, only most recent finite values are considered in the final product. If no finite value is found in a specified interval, then the composite value is nan. This is similar to stacking raster layers in photoshop or gimp.

[image: Time Series Composite, most recent value first]

What I've learned in my recent `x-array` explorations is that more than often the solution to `x-array` problems involves avoiding manual dissection of `x-array` data-structures(however tempting it may be).

I was wondering if python `x-array` had a built in way of handling problems like compositing? Any tips on how I should go about approaching this problem? I'm primarily looking for either more knowledge about x-arrays or a solution to the compositing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't yet have this functionality built-in to xarray yet (contributions would be welcome!). See https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/835 for the issue tracker. Eventually, this will probably go under the name of `combine_first`.

Comment: Thanks again for the speedy reply, and for the invitation to contribute!   
Your link references an `ops` function called `choose` that doesn't exist yet.  I'm guessing the `first_notnull` is just a lower rank array containing time indices, and choose is selecting the proper values from higher rank matrices?

Comment: Yes -- `ops.choose` would simply dispatch to either `dask.array.choose` or `numpy.choose` depending on the type of the input, like the other wrappers in `ops`.

Comment: Does/will x-array take advantage of `dask` in the future?

Comment: Yes, xarray already supports dask.array objects for nearly every operation: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html